# how to get id passed from anchor tag in a div init event?

Tags: asp.net, html, query-string, anchor

```
 <div class="km-scroll-container">
      <ul id="mymenuList" class="item-list km-listview km-listgroup" data-style="inset">
             <li >
                <a href="menu?id=xxx">Menu Name</a>
             </li>   
       </ul>
 </div>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
     <li>Data</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

When i click on a href it take to next div.so here in menu div how to get that id?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I gather you want to use some JavaScript for this task, can you post what you have so far?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in javascript perhaps?

Comment: yes i tried this [link](http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/parsing-query-strings-for-get-data/) it returns null.

Comment: i know how to get the query string to page in javascript but how to do this between <div>'s ?

Answer (score 0):

That particular type of interaction needs to occur on the client meaning you've have to use Javascript.  There are a couple methods you can employ, here's one very quick take...

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#menuNav').bind('click' , function(){
                    $('html,body').scrollTop( $('#menu').offset().top );

                })
            })
        </script>
```

...using the following adjusted HTML...

```
<div class="km-scroll-container">
              <ul id="mymenuList" class="item-list km-listview km-listgroup" data-style="inset">
                     <li >
                        <a id="menuNav">Menu Name</a>
                     </li>   
               </ul>
         </div>
        <div id="menu">
          <ul>
             <li>Data</li>
          </ul>
         </div>
```

Note: the 'id' tag of the anchor ref AND the removal of the 'src' attribute.  The 'id' is needed for jquery to find specific tag (yes, there are other ways but for clarity) and the 'src' is removed as the anchor tag will re-navigate back to itself as it needs to consume the navigation.  Format the anchors as appropriate...

There are other scroll tech's you can employ, e.g. the [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin.

Comment: Here i need to get the id which i was passing!

Comment: Within the handler for the menuNav element you can refer to the current item using 'this'.  If your menu / div are not dynamically generated then you can easily can the event wiring using a client-side array.

Comment: in init event, i'm bindig template like:
 <script id="menuTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template"> 
     <a class="details-link" data-role="listview-link" href="\#mymenu?id=${menu_uid}" onclick="assigntohidden()">
   <h2>${data.menu_name}</h2>            
  </a>
So i'm doing this dynamically.If possible how to get that menu_id in  
onclick event?
      
    </script>

Comment: Well can can utilise the 'href' to pass through a value and process as necessary.  Unfortunately clicking a anchor tag will cause a navigation using the technique I've provided.  Using a different object will prevent this but you'll need to pass the value as an attribute.  Alternatively, use the anchor tag and see if the scrollTo library prevents the navigation...

Comment: i used onclick="assigntohidden(this.href)", and it returns http://localhost:1234/Project/menu.aspx#!

Comment: Don't use Javascript, use Jquery to wire these events on the client-side.  Try and use the code sample above and refactor as necessary.